# What is the adjoint operator between two inner product space with different scalar fields

Tags: adjoint-operators

Is the adjoint operator defined for any two inner product spaces with possibly different scalar fields?

Here is a confusing example. Assume that $H_{1}$ is an inner product space defined on the set of **hermitian** matrices over the **real** vector space. And $H_{2}$ is an inner product space defined on the set of **complex** matrices over the **complex** vector space.

Let $T:H^{n} \rightarrow C^{n}$ be a linear operator from the hermitian matrices to complex matrices. Then its adjoint is the unique $T^{*}$ such that
$$\langle TX,Y\rangle_{H_{2}} = \langle X, T^{*}Y\rangle_{H_{1}}$$

But $\langle TX,Y\rangle_{H_{2}}$ is a complex number, and $\langle X, T^{*}Y\rangle_{H_{1}}$ is a real number. How could they be equal for any $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: No, it's simply not defined, basically because of the problem you posed.

Comment: I see. So the textbook definition about its existence and uniqueness is actually not precisely correct, if they do not mention that the scalar field is the same.